# assignment operator about list in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python, I cannot understand assignment operator clearly, for example:

```
list1 = ["Tom", "Sam", "Jim"]
list2 = list1
```

the above two statements bind 'list1' and 'list2' to `["Tom", "Sam", "Jim"]`, the question is, 
if a operator like below:

`list1[1] = "Sam's sister"`, if the assignment statement is considered as binding, too, then `list2[1]` is still associated with "Sam", the result is that modifying `list1` does not affect the `list2`, even though Python presents the opposite output, another question is whether `list1[1]` can be regarded as a variable as `list1` and `list2` in Python.

can anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, list1[1] can be treated as a variable, but make sure that the list actually has at least two elements. Otherwise Python will complain that the index 1 couldn't be accessed.

Comment: Related: [How to clone or copy a list?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2612802)

Answer (score 4):

In your example the identifiers `list1` and `list2` are references to the same underlying object (*just different names for the same thing*).

`id()` can be used to see if the *same* underlying object is being referenced.

```
>>> list1 = ["Tom", "Sam", "Jim"]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> id(list1)
44259368
>>> id(list2)
44259368
```

To create a copy of the defined list use the `[:]` notation, or `deepcopy` as Matthew has mentioned.  You'll notice that when this is done the location/id has changed.

```
>>> list3 = list1[:]
>>> id(list3)
44280208
```

About the id command:

```
>>> help(id)
Help on built-in function id in module __builtin__:

id(...)
    id(object) -> integer

    Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
    simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right, they aren't the same.  Assignment to a bare name in Python (`name = ...`) is a different operation than assignment to anything else.  In particular it is different from item assignment (`name[0] = ...`) and attribute assignment (`name.attr = ...`).  They all use the equal sign, but the latter two are manipulable with hooks (`__setitem__` and `__setattr__`), can call arbitrary code, and are generally under the control of the programmer.  Assignment to a bare name is not under the control of the Python programmer.  You can't affect what it does; it always just binds the right hand side to the name on the left hand side.

This can be confusing, because people are used to thinking that the equals sign is what makes an "assignment".  But in Python, in order to understand what operation is taking place, you really have to look on the left of the equals sign and see what kind of thing is being assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

BrenBarn is absolutely right about everything, but here is another way to look at it that might be easier to understand:

Your first statement creates a list with those values, then makes list1 point to it.  The second statement makes list2 point to exactly the same memory space as list1.  (You can see this by running id on both of them after the second statement).

At that point list1 and list2 are essentially both references to the same mutable list.  When you change that list, list1 and list2 are still both referencing the same actual list and using either to access it will give you the same thing.

I did a blog post about a related topic [recently](http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/class-and-instance-variables-in-python-2-7/) and Python Conquers the Universe also talks about a similar topic [here](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/).

Answer (score 0):

BrenBam has a good explanation of what is going on. `deepcopy` a way to get around it:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> list1 = ["Tom", "Sam", "Jim"]
>>> list2 = deepcopy(list1)
>>> list1[1] = "Sam's sister"
>>> list1
['Tom', "Sam's sister", 'Jim']
>>> list2
['Tom', 'Sam', 'Jim']
```

Good programming style will make it rare to have to actually use `deepcopy` though.